# How to ignore parent css style

Tags: css

I'm wondering how to ignore a parent style and use the default style (none). I'll show my specific case as an example but I'm pretty sure this is a general question.

```
<style>
#elementId select {
    height:1em;
}
</style>

<div id="elementId">
    <select name="funTimes" style="" size="5">
        <option value="test1">fish</option>
        <option value="test2">eat</option>
        <option value="test3">cows</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Ways I do not want to solve this problem:

- I cannot edit the stylesheet where the "#elementId select" is set, my module won't have access that.
- Preferably not override the height style using the style attribute.

For example using firebug i can turn off the parent style and all is well, this is the effect I am going for.

**Once a style is set, can it be disabled or must it be overridden?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It must be overridden. You could use:

```
<!-- Add a class name to override -->
<select name="funTimes" class="funTimes" size="5">

#elementId select.funTimes {
   /* Override styles here */
}
```

Make sure you use `!important` flag in css style e.g. `margin-top: 0px !important` [What does !important mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css)

You could use an attribute selector, but since that isn't supported by legacy browsers (read IE6 etc), it's better to add a class name

Comment: I keep getting nagged saying _You should avoid the `!important` wherever you can_

Answer (score 65):

You could turn it off by overriding it like this:

height:auto !important;

Comment: I would advise against using `!important` in your production markup - it should really only be used when debugging.

Comment: @Amicable can you explain why this is not advisable?

Comment: @pipo_dev there are a lot of articles online which could explain it better than I could in a comment and with examples.
It a nutshell, it's a hack. 99% of the time it's used in lei of a proper fix which would result in better and more maintainable CSS.
Some acceptable uses of `!important` include utility classes and backwards compatibility hacks for ancient browsers like IE7

Comment: deosnt work. pagnation is the last td in the table.

.detailTable td{
     width: 50%;
}
.pagnation{
 width: 100% !important;
}

Comment: I don't agree with @Amicable. There really is no alternative to using `!important` when you're stuck with a parent theme that you have no control over but still want to override.

Comment: +1 on @JustinSkiles. Sometimes you are working with a lib which you don't have control to but it overrides some of your css that you need `!important`, because they are important to you!

Answer (score 26):

This got bumped to the top because of an edit ... The answers have gotten a bit stale, and not as useful today as another solution has been added to the standard.

There is now an "all" shorthand property.

```
#elementId select.funTimes {
   all: initial;
}
```

This sets all css properties to their initial value ... *note* some of the initial values are inherit; Resulting in some formatting still taking place on the element.

Because of that pause required when reading the code or reviewing it in the future, don't use it unless you most as the review process is a point where errors/bugs can be made! when editing the page. But clearly if there are a large number of properties that need to be reset, then "all" is the way to go.

Standard is online here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#all-shorthand

Comment: I'm building a modal do block websites, this was be solution for my HTML tags not being overwrites by the websites styles.

Comment: `all` does not reset any properties set by `nth-child()` on the parent. For example `<table class="parent_table">` contains `<table class="child_table">`. `.parent_table tr > *:nth-child(1)` will override `all: initial;` on `.child_table`.

Answer (score 11):

The all property in CSS resets all of the selected element’s properties, except the direction and unicode-bidi properties that control text direction.

```
.module {
  all: unset;
}
```

The point of it is allowing for component-level resetting of styles. Sometimes it’s far easier to start from scratch with styling rather than fight against everything that is already there.

```
/* -------- For Your code -------- */
#elementId select.funTimes {
  all: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can create another definition lower in your CSS stylesheet that basically reverses the initial rule. you could also append "!important" to said rule to make sure it sticks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this

height:auto !important;

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation while working on a joomla website.

Added a class name to the module to be affected. In your case:

```
<select name="funTimes" class="classname">
```

then made the following single line change in the css. Added the line

```
#elementId div.classname {style to be applied !important;}
```

worked well!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly:
you can use `auto` in the `CSS` like this `width: auto;` and it will go back to default settings.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense for CSS to have a way to simply add an additional style (in the head section of your page, for example, which would override the linked style sheet) such as this:

```
<head>
<style>
#elementId select {
    /* turn all styles off (no way to do this) */
}
</style>
</head>
```

and turn off all previously applied styles, **but there is no way to do this**. You will have to override the height attribute and set it to a new value in the head section of your pages.

```
<head>
<style>
#elementId select {
    height:1.5em;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of values that can be used to undo CSS rules: initial, unset & revert.
More details from the CSS Working Group at W3C:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#defaulting-keywords

As this is 'draft' not all are fully supported, but unset and initial are in most major browsers, revert has less support.

Answer (score -2):

Please see below typescript for re-applying css class again to an element to override parent container (usually a framework component) css styles and force your custom styles. Your app framework (be it angular/react, probably does this so the parent container css was re-applied and none of your expected effects in css-class-name is showing up for your child element. Call this.overrideParentCssRule(childElement, 'css-class-name'); to do what the framework just did (call this in document.ready or end of event handler):

```
      overrideParentCssRule(elem: HTMLElement, className: string) {
        let cssRules = this.getCSSStyle(className);
        for (let r: number = 0; r < cssRules.length; r++) {
          let rule: CSSStyleRule = cssRules[r];
          Object.keys(rule.style).forEach(s => {
            if (isNaN(Number(s)) && rule.style[s]) {
              elem.style[s] = rule.style[s];
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

- Mike Zheng tradrejoe@gmail.com

Comment: Can you explain why one should use typescript for such a simple requirement?

Comment: This solution is very complex in relation with the very simple question