# What does !important mean in CSS?

Tags: css

What does `!important` mean in CSS?

Is it available in CSS 2? CSS 3?

Where is it supported? All modern browsers?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: ... something to avoid whenever possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read !important in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369216/how-do-you-read-important-in-css), [What are the implications of using “!important” in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) and also see: [when to use !important property in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css), [When to use “!important” to save the day (when working with CSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042497/when-to-use-important-to-save-the-day-when-working-with-css)

Comment: Not important. (Web developer joke).

Comment: With the introduction of CSS layers in near future, this can become be used less if the code is organized properly.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

It means, essentially, what it says; that 'this is important, ignore subsequent rules, and any usual [specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809024/1497596) issues, apply *this* rule!'

In normal use a rule defined in an external stylesheet is overruled by a style defined in the `head` of the document, which, in turn, is overruled by an in-line style within the element itself (assuming equal specificity of the selectors). Defining a rule with the `!important` 'attribute' (?) discards the normal concerns as regards the 'later' rule overriding the 'earlier' ones.

Also, ordinarily, a more specific rule will override a less-specific rule. So:

```css
a {
    /* css */
}
```

Is normally overruled by:

```css
body div #elementID ul li a {
    /* css */
}
```

As the latter selector is more specific (and it doesn't, normally, matter where the more-specific selector is found (in the `head` or the external stylesheet) it will *still* override the less-specific selector (in-line style attributes will *always* override the 'more-', or the 'less-', specific selector as it's *always* more specific.

If, however, you add `!important` to the less-specific selector's CSS declaration, it will have priority.

Using `!important` has its purposes (though I struggle to think of them), but it's much like using a nuclear explosion to stop the foxes killing your chickens; yes, the foxes will be killed, but so will the chickens. And the neighbourhood.

It also makes debugging your CSS a nightmare (from personal, empirical, experience).

Comment: It is also confusing for many developers as in many programming languages the prefix ! means *not*.

Comment: One purpose for !important would be in a GreaseMonkey script where you are purposely overriding other people's CSS that's likely more specific than yours.

Comment: Officially the W3 [calls it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) a "rule".

Comment: What if !important is present in both external style sheet and header of the document. Which styling will get override?

Comment: Under those circumstances, if the rule is equally specific, then the normal CSS rules apply: the style defined 'last' is applied.

Comment: at least it's not sarcastic and says `important!` (important NOT)

Comment: You wrote : 'In normal use a rule defined in an external stylesheet is overruled by a style defined in the head of the document'. It is wrong.

Comment: Useful if: Modifying large css hierarchies without understanding them. E.g.: Applying finishing touches to your page after applying a css framework. Injecting css code into webpages by browser extensions or other means (wordpress e.g.)

Comment: So, !important means its not important and it must be avoided

Comment: @JDSmith I'm not sure it does - the "rule" reference I think is referring to rules in general, which (apart from at-rules) are some selectors and some declarations to apply - the closest I can see for an actual name for this is a "marker" - from 'the second declaration will also win due to being marked "!important"'.

Comment: @jake it's a little confusing as they seem to use it interchangeably - e.g. when they say, 'Both author and user style sheets may contain "!important" declarations, and user "!important" rules override author "!important" rules.' Here they seem to mean that an "!important rule" is a rule containing an !important declaration/marker.

Answer (score 143):

> The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have
> the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has
> the !important property will always be applied no matter where that
> rule appears in the CSS document.

So, if you have the following:

```
.class {
   color: red !important;
}
.outerClass .class {
   color: blue;
}
```

the rule with the important will be the one applied (not counting [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg))

I believe `!important` appeared in CSS1 so every browser supports it (IE4 to IE6 with a partial implementation, IE7+ full)

Also, it's something that you don't want to use pretty often, because if you're working with other people you can override other properties.

Comment: IE4+, actually, with bugs, up to and including 6.

Comment: The confusion happens as `!` is a symbol for NOT in some languages but it's clearer now.

Comment: I'm especially glad that you included the syntax for using `!important`. CSS is different enough from other languages that it's easy to forget how to use certain things.

Comment: @Si8 - Yes, because of that confusion, I've always thought "they" should have defined it as `important!`, or maybe `IMPORTANT!`, rather than `!important`. I wonder if anyone (who might read this) knows why they defined it with the punctuation in front? Obviously, it's way too late to change it now.

Answer (score 25):

`!important` is a part of CSS1.

Browsers supporting it: IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+.

It means, something like:

*Use me, if there is nothing important else around!*

Cant say it better.

Comment: `!important` isn't limited to Safari 3+ only; it has supported it from the very beginning like all other non-IE browsers. IE understands it from version 4 onward, but it only supports it bug-free starting from version 7.

Answer (score 15):

It is used to influence sorting in the CSS cascade when sorting by origin is done.
It has nothing to do with specificity like stated here in other answers.

Here is the priority from lowest to highest:

1. browser styles
2. user style sheet declarations (without !important)
3. author style sheet declarations (without !important)
4. !important author style sheets
5. !important user style sheets

**After** that specificity takes place for the rules still having a finger in the pie.

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade
- https://russmaxdesign.github.io/maxdesign-slides/02-css/207-css-cascade.html

Comment: As @fabian-barney pointed out `!important` is a modifier for the *cascading order* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade (see the table for reference).

Answer (score 8):

It changes the rules for override priority of css cascades.  See [the CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules).