# Styling the RadMenu

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radmenu

I want to be able to accomplish several things with the menu, but am having a hard time trying to figure it out....

Make the font bold
Make the font size larger
Make the border color red
Align the items all the way to the right (instead of the left)

Can someone inform me how I can accomplish this?

Below, is my markup..

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage0.master.cs"
    Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="App_Themes/style0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Network Performance Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style000.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div.RadMenu2
        {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript1.5"></script>
<asp:contentplaceholder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:contentplaceholder>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="top_corner">
            </div>
            <div id="main_container">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="http://wmsatsea.com/">
                            <img src="images/wmslogo.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu2" runat="server" Width="85%" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large"
                            BorderColor="Red">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Reports">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Satellite Availability"
                                            NavigateUrl="SatReport_Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Call Attempts"
                                            NavigateUrl="CA_Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Minutes of Usage"
                                            NavigateUrl="MinUsage_Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Dropped Call %"
                                            NavigateUrl="Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Call Success Rate %"
                                            NavigateUrl="Success_Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="CrewzFone Sales"
                                            NavigateUrl="Crewzfone_Sales.aspx" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Contact Us" NavigateUrl="http://wmsatsea.com/default.aspx">
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="WMS Website" NavigateUrl="http://wmsatsea.com/">
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Revenue">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Revenue" NavigateUrl="~/Revenue/ManageSubscriptions.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="SMS Count" NavigateUrl="MobileSMS_Container.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" ExpandMode="ClientSide" Text="Carrier Activity"
                                            NavigateUrl="MoActivity_Container.aspx" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadMenu>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                </form>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <div id="footWrap">
            <div id="footPanel">
                <div id="footNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Online Support</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Report Requests</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="blank">
                                |</div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="copyright">
                    <p>
                        © Copyright WMS. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Designed By: Software Development Team</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### [!important](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9245353/662581)

This is the most *important* thing you knew to do what you want with RadMenu.

The second is to set **`EnableEmbeddedSkins`** property to false.

---

**Some links:**

- [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu-appearance-item-css-class.html)
- [USING CSS WITH RADMENU](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/menu/using-css-with-radmenu.aspx)

---

And for a quick view, you can change the Text on RadMenu by using the following tag

- `.RadMenu .rmItem .rmExpandDown` - Only the "header" menu.
- `.RadMenu .rmText` - All text menu

Comment: The important PUN was funny for me at least =X

Answer (score 0):

You need to override telerik's css.  Use a combination of viewsource and firebug to do this the most efficiently.  Also this awesome link with the css class heirarchy of the radmenu has helped me buckets in the past.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu-appearance-css-file.html