# About css and !important tag

Tags: css, styles

Can anybody explain what in reality do !important in css styles?

I when i lok on other site css sometimes they use it, but why? I'm not realy understending the !important "job" :D

Thank You...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !important in CSS mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `!important` rule is a way to make your `CSS cascade` but also have the rules you
 feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the `!important` property
 will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.
 So if you wanted to make sure that a property always applied, you would add the `!important` property 
to the tag. 
So, to make the paragraph text always red, in the above example, you would write:

```
p { color: #ff0000 !important; }
 p { color: #000000; }
```

Using `!important` in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come...

**[More about this](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)**

**[More about this link 2](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)**

`!important` is a part of CSS1.

Comment: from `C` point of view it is funny that `not important` actually **is** important

Comment: This is not correct, an `!important` rule will **not** *"always be applied no matter where that rule appears"*. These rules merely [take precedence over rules without `!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules). The `!important` rules am sich cascade as well, so different `!important` rules can override eachother normally.

Answer (score 1):

### What is it?

`!important` overrides other styles that don't have it. Here is a basic order of priority for CSS:

1. Rules with `!important`
2. More specific rules

   ```
   .classNameA .classNameB {} /* more specific */
   .classNameB {}
   ```
3. The order of the rules

   ```
   .classNameB {}
   .classNameB {} /* takes priority */
   ```

### Example

```
.classNameB .classNameA {
    background-color: red;
}
.classNameA {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Despite `.classNameA` being more specific in the first rule, the `background-color` of `.classNameA` is `blue` because of `!important`.

### Should you use it?

No, avoid it at all costs. Only ever use it if it's absolutely necessary and if you find yourself in a situation where it is, consider refactoring your CSS. The reason for this is because it's difficult to change your CSS when you have `!important` rules all over the place. It's also an indicator of bad CSS design.

### Further reading

- [Smashing magazine - !important CSS Declarations: How and When to Use Them](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)
- [CSS Tricks - When Using !important is The Right Choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: It's more like 1.a instructions with !important and more specific selector (than another instruction also with !important but a less specific selector) / 1.b instructions with !important and order of the rules they appear in. Then your existing 2 and 3. Also inline styles and CSS user with !important (always wins) and without !important (wins over UA default CSS, loses against CSS author with or without !important)

Answer (score 0):

`!important` sets the `priority` on the css atributes. If you have two same CSS properties with some different values, one `!important` mark will set that priority as HIGH.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, latter CSS declarations overrule earlier. So if you have declared, in the style sheet, a certain background color for a certain element, and the style block on the page itself, or an inline style, declares another background color for that element, the style block or inline style overrules the style sheet.

If you add `!important` to the declaration in the style sheet, that declaration is not overruled.