# CSS background image issue

Tags: css, background-image

So I have a wrapper div with a background image that covers the whole page.
This works generally... I can maximize the browser and the background covers completely, BUT if there is a scroll, the image stops at the point of scroll.

This image shows the scrolling and the gap from the [jsFiddle example/1](http://jsfiddle.net/2b3sB/1/) :
[image]

```
#wrapper
{
    background: url("../../Images/bgMain.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and the inner div

```
#inner
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Any advice would be helpful.
thanks

Comment: 'stops at the point of scroll' ... meaning what

Comment: It only exists in visible window. It will scale to the size of the window, but it won't show if you scroll.

Comment: My guess is that this will require some javascript.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: Go here for working examples : http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/more-examples.html  and here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it wasn't the route I wanted to take... by setting the image and all of its parameters in `body` rather than a div, I can get the behavior I am looking for.

I don't know why that is exactly... somehow body is treated different than a div (though I do have a reset script, so I would not expect that to be the case)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the fixed width on .inner

```
.inner{
    //...
    width:980px;//this appears to be breaking the css3 background-size
}
```

A possible solution is to apply min-width on the .wrapper

```
#wrapper {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/400/300") no-repeat 50% 0 scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:980px;
}
```

This however means that your cute cat will be enormous on tiny screens (but as you have applied fixed width on .inner this might not matter)

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b3sB/5/)

Comment: you may also need to remove `fixed` from the position element of background

Comment: No, it is a large image that scales with the siz of the browser. But it is only ever as large as the viewable window... so if the content overflows and you scroll, the image doesn't scale. If you maximize the browser, it does.

Comment: @aserwin Updated answer, changed tack (I actually looked at your jsfiddle) and have possible solution BUT I think you found some odd/intentional render behaviour of css3 attribute

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something that might do what you're looking to do-
Anything's worth a shot, right?

```
    background: #000 url(**snip**) no-repeat 50% 0 fixed !important;
```

Try adding the **!important** to the end of your css, it "over-rides" any other styling from other classes, ect. You never know, it might work - but it might also break something else.

What !important does can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean).

Comment: Nope this is not the problem - the OP has used a css3 attribute (background-size) which appears to have a bug or some odd/intentional behaviour when it contains a fixed width child which is larger than the parents 100% width