# KendoUI Grid without borders request

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo ASP.NET-MVC

Our designer wants a grid that has no borders or frames and no alternating row backgrounds. Basically a white box without lines. It's for financial reports. plain and simple.

There should be a monocolored header and footer row where the column names and paging go.

Is this achievable? We don't want to edit too much the main CSS as the rest of the controls on the site should have borders and colors. It's just the grid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
.k-grid, .k-grid * {
    background: white !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

This forces all background for k-grid to white removing gradients and background images and sets borders to 0px (no border).

Comment: what does !important do?

Comment: Overwrites ulterior definitions for background unless they are also "important" (check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9245353/1802671))