# jQuery show element with display:none !important

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have assigned an element a class which has following CSS:

```
.cls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

When I try to show this element with jQuery

```
$(".cls").show();
```

It does not work.

How can I show this element?

Comment: Do you want to `hide` or `show`?

Comment: You can't hide using show.

Comment: :) My apologies, I want to show

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```js
jQuery('.cls').attr('style','display:block !important');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tw33c/)

Comment: wouldn't recommend inline styling, makes the markup very hard to maintain.

Comment: @TarunPai not false! Using a toggleClass() logic could be a better approach but could depend what OP is looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff yep :) answer is legit by all means.

Comment: What's the benefit of this over `.css()`?

Comment: @BramVanroy .css() method cannot be used here because you cannot get rid off the !important statment

Comment: When using `.attr('style', ...)` make sure You will not overwrite other styles applied to the element.

Answer (score 7):

Although question has been asked long back but its still relevant for new coders/beginners. Generally this situation comes when you have already applied some class which overriding the `display` behavior using `!important` property.

Other answers are also relevant to the question and its a matter of achieving the same goal with different approach. I would recommend to achieve it using already available classes in the same library (bootstrap here), instead of writing custom class as these days when most of us are using **Bootstrap classes** to build the layout.

```
<div id='container' class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
.....
</div>
```

If you see in the above code, we are using `d-flex` class for setting display property of this container. Now if I am trying to `show/hide` this container using

`$('#container').show()`

## or

`$('#container').hide()`

It will not work as per expectation because of

1. As `d-flex` is already using `!important` property
2. Jquery's `show()` method will add `display:block` not `display:flex` to the css property of container.

So I will recommend to use **`hidden`** class here.

## To show container

`$('#container').removeClass('hidden')`

## To hide container

`$('#container').addClass('hidden')`

Comment: Or the class `.invisible`

Answer (score 5):

2 ways of doing this,

1) Remove the `!important` from your `.cls` class,

```
.cls{
   display: none;
}
```

But I assume, you'd have used this elsewhere so it might cause regression.

2) What you could alternatively do is, have a another class and toggle that,

```
.cls-show{
  display: block !important;
}
```

And then in your javascript,

```
$('.cls').addClass(".cls-show");
```

Then when you need to hide it again, you can,

```
$('.cls').removeClass('.cls-show');
```

This will help you keep your markup clean and readable

Answer (score 1):

**!important;** remove all rules and apply the css desfined as **!important;**. So in your case it is ignoring all rules and applying  **display:none**.

So do this:

```
.cls {
  display:none
}
```

See [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

Answer (score 1):

If the only property in the CLS class selector is the display one, you can do this and don't need to add any extra classes or modify the inline style.

To show them:

```
$('.cls').removeClass("cls").addClass("_cls");
```

To hide them:

```
$('._cls').removeClass("_cls").addClass("cls");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this exact issue, here's what I did
first, I added another class to the element, such as:

```
<div class="ui-cls cls">...</div>
```

Then in the javascript:

```
$('.ui-cls').removeClass('cls').show();
```

The nice thing is that you can also have this code to hide it again:

```
$('.ui-cls').hide();
```

and it doesn't matter how many times you hide/show, it'll still work