# How to change text color of a link inside jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change a color of a link inside jQuery accordion. How can I do it?

**css**

```
.x
{
    color: red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="test">
    <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
    <div>111
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
    <div>222
    </div>
    <h3><a href="some_link" class="x">Three</a></h3>
    <div> bla</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfzaC/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively

```
.x
{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just for my curiosity, Why do you think that `!important` is very important?

Comment: Have a look at David Thomas' post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean

Comment: I already know the meaning, but just wanted to know, is it really necessary to use it? As this will explicitly apply the rule overriding the others which is a bad css practice - @Gven

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your CSS at the bottom.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active {
        color:red;
}
```

This will make the black color to red.

Also, declare your css after `jquery-ui.css`

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XfzaC/7/)**

**EDIT**

If you need to apply the style to the heeader, you need to create a css for `h3.ui-accordion-header a.x` as below.

**The Code change**

```
h3.ui-accordion-header a.x {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XfzaC/11/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You changed the content and not the header, so it's not what I need

Comment: oh.. In that case, you need to apply css to `h3.ui-accordion-header a.x` For Instance, `h3.ui-accordion-header a.x {
    color: #FF0000;
}` Here is the (WORKING DEMO)[http://jsfiddle.net/XfzaC/11/] - @crazybob

Answer (score 1):

While adding `!important` would work, you should only use it as a last resort, as it can lead to a lot of maintenance problems should you ever need to then override a style with `!important` already set on it.

Instead, use selector precedence to increase the weight of your selector:

```
#test .x {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/XfzaC/8/)

Answer (score 0):

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XfzaC/5/)**

```
.ui-accordion-header a
{
    color: red ;
}
```