# Override CSS visibility

Tags: css, visibility

I have

```
#boxes { visibility: hidden } 
.active { visibility: visible }
```

I want the `div` to be hidden unless `.active` is in use. I tried `<div id="boxes" class="active">` but the `div` was still hidden.

Is there anyway for the `.active` class to override the hidden visibility??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS selectors have "specificity" or weight ([6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) ) which defines what selector takes precedence. Selectors which refer to elements by ID have high weight, so to override it you need more specific selector for "active":

```
#boxes.active { visibility: visible }
```

Or less specific selector for `#boxes` in some way. Class selector is more important than element selector, so it will override `visibility` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EU7e9/) ):

```
div  { visibility: hidden } 
.active { visibility: visible }
```

Comment: 1+ Pairing up the class with the id definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<div>` element is being used as a same-page link with multiple `#boxes`, such as for tabbed pages, you can also use :target. This would allow you to style each one individually:)

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS would change slightly...adding a space after `#boxes`, since the `class` is in a decendent `<div>`.

```
#boxes .box1:target{visibility: visible;}
#boxes .box1:not(:target){visibility: hidden;}
#boxes .box2:target{visibility: visible;}
#boxes .box1:not(:target){visibility: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#boxes.active { visibility: visible !important; }
```

Actually '!important' is not necessary when pairing a div with class, but if it doesn't works for you, just consider this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` for giving the importance of value.
`!import` simple meaning is, It is important than others so execute only it.

```css
#boxes.active { 
    visibility: visible !important; 
}
```

Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css)