# Can you specify that a css class should use the information from one style sheet?

Tags: css

I have a css sheet for a big project that I can't change, "cantChange.css"

I also have a css sheet for a small portion of the project that I am able to change "canChange.css"

Both css sheets describe the style for a certain class -- and cantChange.css is overriding canChange.css.

Is there any way to give priority to a certain style sheet for a URL? Is there another way to do this with css specificity rules?

Comment: Can we see an example of a CSS definition you want to override? As you mentioned, I suggest using CSS specificity to make certain definitions take precedence over others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

The loading order of course is important. You should load "canChange.css" after you loaded the other one. On top of that CSS offers `!important` . Which allows for something like:

```
background-color: blue !important;
```

If that still doesn't do anything add an id to the element in question and style that one. IDs are always higher prioritized then classes or common selectors.

Comment: !important is a blunt tool and should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options to address this:

- Make your selector more specific (e.g. `#body #small-project .cool-class`)
- Apply the styles inline (e.g. `style="color: #000"`)
- If you can change the order in which the stylesheets are loaded, load `canChange.css` file after `cantChange.css`
- Give priority using `!important` ([What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean))

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own declaration MORE SPECIFIC to override the others.

For example:

```
body.someclass .anotherclass { ... }    

<body class="someclass">
```

will always override `.anotherclass { ... }`