# How to reuse and override Css style?

Tags: html, css

ok, here is myResource.css

```
.gwtCellButton button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  ....more styles here...

}

.gwtCellButton button:active {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.gwtCellButton button:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}
```

Now I want to have `.gwtCellButtonSmall` that is exactly like `.gwtCellButton` except that it has `padding: 1px 2px;`

Ofcourse if i do like this, then I can duplicate code:

```
.gwtCellButtonSmall button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  ....more styles here...

}

.gwtCellButtonSmall button:active {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.gwtCellButtonSmall button:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have two elements with similar styles with one having different `padding`.

Is so, you can share styles between the two elements:

```
.gwtCellButton button, .gwtCellButtonSmall button{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    ...
}
```

Then use [`!important`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean) to override the `padding` for the specific element:

```
.gwtCellButtonSmall button{
    padding: 1px 2px !important
}
```

Or you could use something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

Comment: There's no need to use "!important" if you ensure that you put the more specific selector below the more general selector.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to duplicate any code or, worse, use `!important`.

This problem can be solved through the use of modifier classes by specifying two classes on each HTML element: a base `gwtCellButton` class and a modifier class (`regular` and `small` in this example).

```
.gwtCellButton button {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gwtCellButton.regular button {
  padding: 5px 7px;
}

.gwtCellButton.small button {
  padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

Using the `!important` declaration unnecessarily can lead to [specificity issues](http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/) down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important`. The property which has `!important` overrides the exactly property if there are any other.

So your case,

```
 padding: 1px 2px!important;
```

Heavily using them causes you some problems sometimes. Thus, do not forget to have a quick look at [this summary](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) too.

Comment: There's no need to use "!important" if you ensure that you put the more specific selector below the more general selector.