# CSS - Font color is not changing

Tags: html, css, css3pie

i am trying to fix a color of my TEXT color, its just WHITE so same color as background, dispite the fact its color is set for :#1a6eb6 and its set for same value in #submenu ul li .text I am prettz lost in it, can somebody help me with it?

My HTML:

```
 <div class="submenu">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">DISKUSNÍ FÓRUM </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">KOMENTÁŘE </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">ZÁZNAM CHATU </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">UŽÍVATELÉ</a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.submenu{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width:780px;
}

.submenu ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;         
}

.submenu ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */  
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 38px;
    width: 187px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1a6eb6;         
}

.submenu ul li:hover {
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg_hover.png");
    width: 187px;
    height: 38px;             
}

.submenu ul li .text{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;    /* aby sa dala rovnomerne posunut sipka a nie podla dlzky textu*/
    height: 31px;
    width:115px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 5px;         
}

.submenu ul li .horizontal-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/horizontal_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 19px;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;       
} 

.submenu ul li:hover .horizontal-arrow{
    display:none;         
}

.submenu ul li .vertical-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/vertical_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display:none;
    height: 12px;
    width: 19px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;         
} 

.submenu ul li:hover .vertical-arrow{
    display: inline-block;             
}
```

Live Preview can be find on: http://funedit.com/andurit/new/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the color to `.submenu ul li .text a`

```
.submenu ul li .text a{
    color: #1a6eb6;
}
```

Font color was not changing because your styles.css had the below style which was overriding the color you specified to `.submenu ul li .text`

```
li a:link {
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the color of the `<a>` tag because that tag has color white.

something like:

```
.submenu ul li a{
    color: #1a6eb6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many popular user agent stylesheets include a rule that selects `a` and sets its color:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

This is sort of a blue-ish color.  Moreover, your `style.css` has:

```
li a:link {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This overrides the UA stylesheet and is why the link appears white.  You need to actually select the `a` with your rule:

```
.submenu a:link {
    color: #1a6eb6;
}
```

The `:link` part is necessary because of the specificity of the `li a:link` selector.  You could also do `.submenu li a` or some other more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change the color of your text, you probably should use the "a" element like  this:

```
#submenu ul li a{

//your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css line 183 for element to

```
li a:visited
{
color: #1a6eb6;
}
```

Or you could create a new css selector like

```
.submenu ul li a
{
color: #1a6eb6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`style.css line 183` - you have  `li a:visited {color:#f7f7f7};`

`style.cc line 173` - you have `li a:link {color:#f7f7f7;}`

This is I got from chrome console. check these lines in your css file and take out the `color:#f7f7f7`

you can also use the `!important` rule in css to make sure that rule overwrites any other rule.
[What does !important in CSS mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

`.submenu{
    color: #1a6eb6 !important;;
}`