# Bootstrap li a padding 0 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set `padding` to **0 px** for hyperlink inside the `li` tag but its not working. If I set that in *inline* for that specific hyperlink then its working fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
                <li class="active"><a href="nokia-phones-1.php">Nokia</a></li>
                <li><a href="samsung-phones-9.php">Samsung</a></li>
                <li><a href="motorola-phones-4.php">Motorola</a></li>
                <li><a href="sony-phones-7.php">Sony</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <h2>Most Viewed</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");

li a {
padding: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TxdAm/

I even tried

```
ul li {    padding: 0px;}
```

and

```
li  {    padding: 0px;}
```

and

```
a  {    padding: 0px;}
```

but still its not working.

How can I set the `padding` to **0px** for hyperlinks inside the `unordered list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the class of bootsrap, just add this CSS rule:

```
.nav > li > a {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

In Bootstrap this rule's value is 10px 15px, so this should fix it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `!important` in CSS rule

```
li a {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

It will work. For more info about *!important*: look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)**