# Do css rules in external stylesheet get overridden even if they have higher specificity than embedded or inline css rules?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have a doubt do css rules in external stylesheet get overridden by the embedded or inline css rules even if they have higher specificity.

```
//external stylesheet
p { color: blue !important; }
//inline css rule
p#test { color:red; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !important in CSS mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

Comment: The rules have the same selector `p`, so the specificity is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No important will lock the style completely (unless you use !important again somewhere to override), so you cant override it with inline style

Comment: Of course, !important should be avoided wherever possible, as it is difficult to override and works outside the normal cascade. But one of its valid uses is to override inline styles in plugins etc where you maybe can't get at the code directly - in which case it would be exactly as done here; the blue colour would override the inline red colour.