# Rails - How do I ensure my styles take precedence over Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I'm sure this is a dead simple question, but I can't find a straight forward answer so thought I'd ask here.

I'm building a site using Bootstrap, though want my custom styles to take precedence over Bootstrap's.

I'd imagine it's probably as simple as adjusting the order in my `application.css.scss` file, but my tinkering hasn't found a solution yet.

Currently this file is as follows:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I've just started building this site, and have a couple of Bootstrap grid columns, one of which I'd like to remove the padding from. The other, I've added a background image and height to, no problem. The following code is from `home.css.scss`:

```
.col-md-4 {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg');
  height: 1000px;
} //both of which work

.col-md-8 {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
} //which is overridden by Bootstrap's default styling
```

As I've said, hopefully this is a real simple solution that won't take too much effort to answer. Appreciate any help! Steve.

Comment: Good reading on a subject: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Great read, and I've worked out the answer to my question using it. As the classes matched, Bootstrap was taking precedence due to its position in the cascade. By moving `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";` to the top of `home.css.scss` my styles then take precedence. Thanks a bunch @BroiSatse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the answer using @BroiSatse's great link: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade

As both Bootstrap and my code were referencing the class `.col-md-8`, Bootstrap's styling was taking precedence due to its positioning in the cascade.

By moving `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";` from `application.css.scss` to the top of `home.css.scss`, my styles then take precedence. And everything is working as it should be! Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -3):

You can make use of `!important` . 
What it says; that 'this is important, ignore subsequent rules, and any usual specificity issues, apply this rule!'

```css
p {
    color: red !important;
}
#thing {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="thing">Will be RED.</p>
```

For Example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/9bfc0pgv/)

Reference: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

Comment: Using `!important` is risky, and it should only be used when no other ways are available.

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe - using `goto` is also a workaround in C++. It is a bad practice to place `!important` - it means that a developer doesn't understand CSS specificity and is trying to get rid of C from CSS. Cascading is beautiful, don't kill it.