# margin not applying to h2 element in ionic

Tags: css

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content class="has-header padding coloredBackground">



<h2 class="centerHeading"> Receive your Order by:  </h2>
</ion-content>


</ion-view>
```

css:

```
.centerHeading{
    text-align: center;
    color: #6E6E6E;
    margin-top:20px;

}
```

margin-top or margin for that matter is not wokring at all. How do I fix this?

Demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/6d960c043467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of include your CSS in wrong order. Your `margin-top` is overriding by `ionic.min.css`

You have two options:

### option 1

Change your custom css file include after ionic.min.css

### option2

Define property with `!important`

```
  margin-top: 20px !important;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your margin-top is been getting over-ridden by the ionic.min.css-

Since, in your ionic.min.css file,

```
h2:first-child{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

**Solution 1:**

Either over-ride the css style of h2 by your own css in your style sheet, by following

```
h2:first-child{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
.centerHeading{
    text-align: center;
    color: #6E6E6E;
    margin-top:20px !important;
}
```

Here, is the link that explains about "!important", [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)