# Why the table th font vertical center is not effect in the css?

Tags: html, css

I want set the table th font vertical center，but if It is not effect as I set in CSS like this:

```
.table-display th {
    height: 20px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

and the html is:

```
<table id="rule-table"  class="table table-display table-striped  jambo_table" border="1" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th>Name</th>
......
```

But if I set the vertical-align style in html instead of css,it took effect:

```
<table id="rule-table"  class="table table-display table-striped  jambo_table" border="1" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th style="vertical-align:middle;">Name</th>
  ......
```

what is the problem?

Comment: some css must be overriding this class And when u add inline css it will take effect. Check with developer tools in chrome. also try to use [!important](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9245353/4053389) in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!important` in your `css` class or try below code,

```
.table-display> thead> tr > th {
    height: 20px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. use !important in the css solved the problems.and there happens an other problem:
Html:
    <td class="td-font-left">{{ value }}</td>
and the css:
       .table-display td {
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;!important;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            word-break:break-all;;
     }
and 
    .td-font-left{
        text-align:left;!important;
    }
td-font-left tooks no effect,font is still in center,how to sovle it?

Comment: `!important` should add before the semi colon(;). like - `.td-font-left{ text-align:left !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give !important in the CSS file..That will work.This will override the other css.