# Override inline style with another class for span

Tags: html, css

CSS class

```
.MyLinkList {
  border: 2px solid yellow !important;
  border-left: 2px solid green !important;
  font-family: chiller !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```
<li class="MyLinkList">
  <span style="padding-right: 10px;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:Black;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;">g</span>
</li>
```

For span the inline style is given which getting more priority and our class `MyLinkList` color style etc is not get applied how I can make span takes the `MyLinkList` class style. I know I can use `.MyLinkList span` but I don't want that.

Comment: What reason could be there to not want `.MyLinkList span`?

Comment: use !important.
If you are unaware of it the see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean

Comment: I want to give user more simplicity for using CSS so with one class .MyLinkList he can deal with span also.

Comment: why don't you remove the inline style if you don't need it

Comment: @Aayush Rohatgi Where I can use !important because already used in my class.

Comment: ok you are not using MyLinkList on span so !important won't work for you

Comment: @Aayush Rohatgi inline style is important for be because by default inline style will be applied means if I not given CSS class style.

Comment: use a new class with color marked important and apply it to span.

Comment: or you can do 
.MyLinkList span{color: red !important;}

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can use .MyLinkList span but I don't want that.

It is your only choice.

The span doesn't have `color: inherit`, so it won't take the parent element's style. Only styles that target the span specifically will affect it.

Comment: Appreciate the response but is that no way to use MyLinkList class style for span?

Comment: @santosh — Other than changing the span so the styles affecting it have `inherit` as their values (as implied by this answer): No

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via JavaScript:

- if you need to change one element (this will delete inline styles):

  `var changeMyStyle = document.querySelector(".MyLinkList>span");
   changeMyStyle.style = "";
   changeMyStyle.classList.add("MyLinkList");`
- if you have more span elements that needs to be reseted:

  `var changeThem = document.querySelectorAll(".MyLinkList>span");
  var changeThemLen = changeThem.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < cnahgeThemLen; i++) {
     changeThem[i].style = "";
     changeThem[i].classList.add("MyLinkList");
  }`

Explanation: 
This code will do two things:
 1. It will remove inline style from span element
 2. It will add CSS class to span element

You can add class you already defined or some other class, you can add multiple classes and basically redefine whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to give style which given in my css class .MyLinkList.

Comment: Then you add your class to element. I've updated my answer.

Comment: But by this in class border style also get applied to span:(

Comment: Then define `MySpanStyle` CSS class the way you want it, with or without borders and add it to span in `changeMyStyle.classList.add("MySpanStyle");` and `changeThem[i].classList.add("MySpanStyle");` instead of this class.

Comment: I want to give all style border plus font in single "MyLinkList" Class.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you anymore.... Copy your CSS class or create new one, remove or change border styling and whatever you want for your <span> element(s), rename your class if you copied it, add this class via javascript in a way I explained in my answer and comment bellow...