# Hovering over image and making it bigger

Tags: php, css

```
.thumbnail:hover 
{
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    left:-35px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
}
```

and

```
<td><img src='.$row['spy'].' class="thumbnail" style="width:64px; height:64px;"></td>
```

But it won't work btw I'm using Enjin I'm trying to make an image bigger on hovering over it

Comment: Define `won't work`

Comment: see for yourself here: http://unturnedbf.com/bans

Comment: there is no css it's just     <td><img src='.$row['spy'].' style="width:64px; height:64px;"></td>

Comment: There is no element with class=thumbnail on the page you linked.

Comment: we also use .banlistframe
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
} for the banlist but it seems this doesnt get loaded or something anymore once we have the other css with the :hover

Comment: <td><img src='.$row['spy'].' class="thumbnail" style="width:64px; height:64px;"></td> still doesn't work see on unturnedbf.com/bans

Comment: use important as i mentioned below

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
width:500px !important;
```

and also

```
height:auto !important;
```

This will work and this make your CSS not overridden by other CSS

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `!important` on both your width and height attributes within CSS for it to override the inline styling. :-)

```
.thumbnail:hover{
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    left: -35px;
    width: 500px !important; // notice !important
    height: auto !important;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!important` to force CSS to override the other style.

When using `auto` it resets the element back to default height.

Try using this:

```
width: 500px !important;
height: auto !important;
```

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean/9245360#9245360)

Comment: can you check my answer