# How i can disable bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html

i am trying to Disable the Bootstrap `<pre>`
https://jsfiddle.net/9e6byxe1/

Comment: You must overwrite the style of pre in your css.

Comment: Override the tag with your own CSS file. Make sure this file is below the original bootstrap file, otherwise you have to work with `!important` tags.

Comment: Copy the specificity used by Bootstrap for `<pre>`,  then use it on your custom css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `!important` declaration.

```
pre {
    color: #222222 !important;
}
```

[Read this Stack Overflow answer to see more about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245360/5191455)