# How to overwrite angular 2 material styles?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have this select in angular material:

[image]

Its code :

```
<md-select placeholder="Descuentos y convenios" [(ngModel)]="passenger.discount">
        <md-option [value]="null" [disabled]="true">
            Descuentos
        </md-option>
        <md-option *ngFor="let option of discounts" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
        </md-option>
        <md-option [value]="null" [disabled]="true">
            Convenios
        </md-option>
        <md-option *ngFor="let option of agreements" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
        </md-option>
</md-select>
```

And I would like to have this styles in it:

[image]

I tried to put some classes over md-select and md-option, but not worked.
I would like to have maybe just an example of how to put the background color or the border and that would give me an idea.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The components CSS is not working?

Comment: I exactly do not know how to for example put the border of the options.

Comment: Not all HTML elements that Angular generates are marked with the component name, so the component css has only limited value.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think classes should work, but you may need to use [/deep/](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#-deep-) because of the view encapsulation.

Try this:

```
/deep/ md-select.your-class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

You can also play with [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: Note: the `/deep/` selector, as well as `>>>` and `::ng-deep` are all being deprecated. More information [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). Unfortunately there does not appear to be a replacement.

Comment: There better be a replacement.  That would be a big mistake to remove without one.

Comment: Although its deprecated, but this is still working until now, the fastest and simplest solution.

Comment: On Angular use ::ng-deep .className {
    color: #8d062a !important;
}

Answer (score 21):

The top solutions of `/deep/`, `>>>`  and `::ng-deep` are being deprecated and should no longer be used.

[The recommended method is now view encapsulation](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)

---

**Edit: Word of warning. I do not recommend using this method at all (as of Jan 2019) as setting ViewEncapsulation.None will result in any of that components css becoming global styles (it stops Angular from creating ng_xxx attributes for component scoped css). This will result in global style conflict, especially with lazy loaded module css.**

Our solution to ViewEncapsulation was to override very specific css using highly specific css selectors in 1) global css or 2) creating separate style files for certain views / styles / elements, importing into every component required (e.g. `styleUrls: [material-table-override.css, component.css]`).

---

I used ViewEncapsulation.None to successfully override material table styles within a single component in Angular 6.

On your component:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
// ...
@Component({
    // ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

[Here's a great article on the subject](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

Comment: This solution is in some cases not optimal because it overrides CSS styles of the parent component if a mat-dialog component is being used. A better solution should manipulate material compnents within the boundaries of the dialog component.

Answer (score 13):

If you can solve your style issues with the material 2 scss theming that would be the "right" way hears is a link to there site.
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming.

However I used !important on the styles I didn't want materials styles to overwrite.

Here is how I used it:

```
/*hack to get rid of a scrollbar*/
.cdk-focus-trap-content{
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

/*hack to get rid of a padding on the popup*/
.mat-dialog-container{
     padding: 0px !important;
 }
```

I had a situation where a horizontal scroll bar was showing up in the md-sidenav and I got rid of their default padding on the md-dialog.

Not the most elegant solution but I hope this helps.

This is another StackOverflow question that discusses what !important is.

[What does !important in CSS mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)

Comment: Yeah I'm finding I have to slap !important everywhere to override the Material styles.  This is very annoying.

Answer (score 11):

The correct way to change styles of overlay classes like mat-dialog-container is to use `panelClass` according to [Customizing Angular Material component styles](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md#styling-overlay-components):

Add this to your global stylesheet after your theme setup

```
.myapp-no-padding-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Use the following to open the dialog

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {panelClass: 'myapp-no-padding-dialog'})
```

Comment: I like this and is the cleanest answer I have seen so far.

Answer (score 10):

you can use:

```
::ng-deep {
 .mat-dialog-container{
   padding: 0px 
 }
}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous solution, becouse this will affect all components in whole app. 
If you want it like this, you can override in golbal style.scss.
Otherwise, prefix ng-deep with some selector. Like :host ::ng-deep or .mat-dialog-override::ng-deep...

Answer (score 7):

**::ng-deep** works like a charm for me...  for scss and sass file.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way whenever I have to remove scroll from `mat-sidenav-container`

```
   .mat-sidenav-container-classname ::ng-deep mat-sidenav-content {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: great solution. prevents your changes to mat-sidenav-content in that component from interfering with other instances of mat-sidenav-content

Comment: glad it helped! @clk

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Angular Material, I inspected the select element, checked its classes and tried to overwrite the css rules for material css classes , even tried `!important` flag for style rules. But it was not working.

Moving all such rules from component to index.html worked for me.

```
.mat-select-value,
    .mat-option-text,
    .mat-standard-chip,
    .mat-input-element,
    .mat-menu-item {
         color: #666 !important;
         font-size: 13px !important;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:root` as well

```
:root {
    .mat-dialog-container{
        padding: 0px 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this code.

```
.mat-dialog-container{
     padding: 0px !important;
}
```

If this does not work you can use

```
/deep/.className {
... your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me also faced this kind of situation, but I found a permanent solution to over come this.

If we use ::ng-deep or :root/CLASS_NAME or ViewEncapsulation it may affect other components also. So what you can do is,

> 1. Make sure your global style sheet is present at the end of styles array in your angular.json file

```
"styles": [
      "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "src/styles.css"     <-----------
    ],
```

2. Inspect your code and get the relevant class from the [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvEBH.jpg)
3. Get the relevant class and override it in your global style file (styles.css)

```css
 .mdc-dialog__surface{
    background-color: antiquewhite !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
  }
  
  .cdk-overlay-backdrop.cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

[Updated style output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrI8T.jpg)

4. Similarly you can modify other Angular material components and Bootstrap inbuilt styles also.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone looking for a cleaner approach in 2020, use the panelClass as suggested in the material mat-select [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label). Use the **panelClass** property