# Angular Material 2 mat-slide-toggle change slide distance of thumb

Tags: css, angular-material2

I'm using the mat-slide-toggle element from Angular Material 2, and I made it a bit bigger, but the thumb doesn't move to the end of the container when clicked, and I can't seem to figure out which transform-translate property controls the distance.

The following is a pic of how it looks currently when clicked: [image]

Is someone aware of what property needs to be changed for this to slide to the end? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone Googles this - the correct selector is the following:

```
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(64px,0,0) !important;
}
```

I got the correct answer from [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805152/how-to-style-the-angular2-material-slide-toggle-button), which contains other useful selectors for mat-slide-toggle.