# Angular unfocus tab and set focus to different tab

Tags: css, angular, tabs

I have a Material Tab component in Angular 2.
I want to have a button at the end of the tabs, that acts as a add tab button. Upon clicking on it a new tab is created before it.
I tried putting a button there, but couldn't find how to place it exactly next to the last tab.

So what I did is I added a tab that acts like a button. When this tab is clicked, a new tab is created.

However, when this tab is clicked, it gains focus. While I can change which tab is selected, the tab still has the focused UI (it is colored).
How can I make it lose it's focus completely?

P.S. If there is a way to add a regular button next to the last tab, without making it a tab, this would also be good.

**Edit - Code:**

This is how my tabs are setup:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="selectedTab($event)">
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        Basic Details
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab #categoryTab *ngFor="let table of mCase.Tables; let tableIndex = index" [attr.data-index]="tableIndex">
    <mat-tab>

    <mat-tab #addCategory>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <div color="white" class="center">Add category</div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Code behind:

```
public selectedTab(e) {
    if (e.index == 1 + this.mCase.Tables.length) {
      //Add new category
      this.CreateTable();
      this.selectedIndex = this.mCase.Tables.length;
    }
Promise.resolve().then(() => this.selectedIndex = e.index);
}
```

Comment: Post code code snippets, at least html and javascript.

Comment: @MunimMunna edited with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try add the button like this:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
       Basic Details
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab disabled>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="foo()">
                <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrklwg

By the way, if you are bothered by the button having *disabled like* styles, you can just override that with some custom CSS! :D

Comment: I'm trying to change the disabled style with the following css: .mat-button[disabled] {
    color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    background-color: transparent;
  }
But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @amitairos Hey! I'm glad it worked. Try by adding a class to the button, like `fake-disabled` or whatever you like, and then just change what you want with a classic CSS rule like: `button.fake-disabled: { color: #000; }`.

Comment: @amitairos Hey! Not really, but have a look at this and see if it helps, good luck mate! ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690291/how-to-overwrite-angular-2-material-styles

Comment: Didn't work, but I found that if I set ```[disabled]="false"``` to the button - it can be colored, while the tab is still disabled. So it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.blur()` on the `event.currentTarget` of the button which has been clicked. `.blur()` is the opposite of the `.focus()` method and will remove focus from an element.

In you question you said:

> Upon clicking on it a new tab is created before it.

You didn't add any html, so I just went and created an example of how you can dynamically append buttons to the html via a data bound array.

```
this.buttons.splice(clickedButtonIndex, 0, {Name: "New Button"});
```

To learn about how this works, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index).

This is the crux of the component code that you can use to blur focus on the element.

```
addButton(clickedButtonIndex, event){
    this.buttons.splice(clickedButtonIndex, 0, {Name: "New Button"});
    event.currentTarget.blur();
}
```

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vslscm

In the example, I have set a red background in css to be applied to buttons when they are focused. You can see that when you click on a button, it momentarily will turn red before being toggled off again. Clicking the buttons will add a new button before the button which was clicked.

Comment: Thanks. I edited with my code. blur doesn't work, I don't know why. Maybe I'm not using it correctly with my tabs. Also, I don't have a list of buttons, only tabs. So I used a tab instead of a button for adding a new tab. If you know how to put the button next to each tab, that would also be good.