# Remove weird border on material dialog

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-material-6

I use [**Angular material 6**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) dialog component. It showed a weird `border`. Can you tell me how to remove that? I have tried like below. But it is not working. If I do that inside the browser (inline) then it works. Any clue?

[image]

*dialog.component.html*

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Confirm</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Are you sure wanted to delete the account?</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button cdkFocusInitial [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Delete</button>
</div>
```

*dialog.componet.css*

```
dialog.ng-star-inserted {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: did you try with ```.cdk-overlay-pane{ border:none !important;}```

Comment: and i think this border is for your dialog component you can try : ```dialog{ border:none !important}```

Comment: I have tried both. But no luck yet :(  Any other clue? @fatemefazli

Comment: use like this /deep/ .cdk-overlay-pane{ border:none !important;}

Comment: What did you mean `/deep/ `? @PraveenMP

Comment: Refer this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690291/how-to-overwrite-angular-2-material-styles

Comment: @Sampath Are you able to resolve it?

Comment: No. Still the same issue. I have tried like this: `:host /deep/ .cdk-overlay-pane{ border:none !important;}`  @PraveenMP

Comment: add it in your styles.scss, like so `dialog { border: none !important; }`

Comment: Oh.. Thanks a lot. It works. Please put that as an answer @bodorgergely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way would be to declare style for the dialog inside your `styles.css` file. Like so:

```
dialog { 
  border: none !important;
}
```

The reason the style is not applied when you put it in your component, is because in the component scope you don't have access to the mat-dialog. Your component will be rendered inside the mat-dialog component, in a different component.

Styles defined in the `styles.css` file will be globally applied in your application.