# Ignore body's text-alignment

Tags: html, css

The HTML body is set to text-alignment = center. I know this is not the best approach and I may change in the future as this is giving me a lot of headaches, but my whole website was designed based on this, so I would not like to change this set up right now.

I would like to have a box centered middle, but everything inside that box set to left. at the moment everything inside that box is also set to center. even though the box elements are text-aligment= left.

CSS:

```
.centerAddress{
    width: 40vw;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

html,
body {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   max-width: 960px;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="centerAddress">
     <p style="margin-top: 5%">test</p>
     <p>testt</p>
     <p>test</p>
     <p>test</p>
     <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried !important ?

Comment: Not sure what that is. what is it?

Comment: it will overide any other rule... text-align:left !important;

Comment: Thanks I didnt know that existed.

Comment: You shouldn't need that. Could you move your Code into a code snippet? Also in the given code your body does not have a center text align

Comment: You are creating chaos in the edit reviews by editing the name and address on every posted answer. Is this really the address of a real person? Please consider such things _before_ posting the question.

Comment: Lundin that was my bad! I have to update and edit now as it was personal info.

Comment: Since you don't have enough rep yet, every such edit suggestion you leave pops up in an edit review where other users thinks the edit looks fishy - they don't see the full context. That's why your first edit got rejected. I'll fix this for you, please stop editing the answers for now.

Comment: I have updated my question, so I shouldnt have to edit any new post anyway. there is only two answer with personal detail.

Comment: Yes I noticed. I fixed it now, all good :)

Comment: Thanks :) it was my bad, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `!important` to trump css specificity

```
.centerAddress{
    width: 40vw;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean) for more details

Or you can target all child elements inside the `.centreAddress` box by using the `*` selector

```
.centerAddress *  {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Make that

```
.centerAddress p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

to be effective on the `p` tags in there, which otherwise might inherit the centering from `body`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the body alignments. Use two classes in css

```
html,
body {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   max-width: 960px;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

in Html use these classes wherever you want. Like this,

```
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Body Header</h1>
    <div class="centerAddress text-left">
        <p style="margin-top: 5%">test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah i know this way, but if I do that now there is alot of updating to my code. as the website is near done.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution, let me know if this helps you

```css
.centerAddress {
  width: 40vw;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

body.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body class="center">
  <div class="centerAddress">
    <p style="margin-top: 5%">test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```