# Change font color inside nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm a newcomer and I want to change the color of the font inside the navbar but cant find any solution, here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">testteee</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <header>
    <p>teste</p>
  </header>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: purple;
  border: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px grey;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px grey;
}
```

Any additional tips would be great for my development :)

Comment: What bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7

Comment: Use !important to overwrite the default styles of bootstrap, check my example answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need, but I'd suggest you to to change this from sass/scss variables. It might be a long way because you have to learn how to build bootstrap css files in a nodejs environment, [this](https://www.codementor.io/trey/create-custom-bootstrap-build-with-scss-du107p62v) can help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
          background-color: grey;
        }
        .navbar-custom {
          background-color: purple;
          border: transparent;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px grey;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .navbar-custom .navbar-header a,
        .navbar-custom .navbar-header a:hover {
          color: #fff;
        }
        .navbar-custom ul.navbar-nav li a:hover {
          background-color: gray;
          color: #fff;
        }
        .navbar-custom ul.navbar-nav a {
          color: #fff;
        }
        .navbar-custom ul.navbar-nav a:hover {
          color: blue;
        }

        main {
          width: 60%;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 0 auto;
          box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <p>main content</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I think it's a bad practice and it's not scalable to use !important.

You can read something about [when to use important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) and perhaps some [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) :)

Comment: To say something is bad practice that is valid and up to date code is misleading.  !important simply over rules previous set styles that is all.  If it was bad practice why is it usable and not depreciated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean

Comment: Please take a look at bootstrap source code. Or other like bootstrap. Or you can read this [funny quote](https://twitter.com/stefsull/status/70631020352913408) :) Of course, there are a few potentially good use cases for !important, but I think it's not the case here.

Comment: I will have to agree with @zalog here, it is not the case to use the !important.

Answer (score 1):

Use color in CSS to change a fonts color.

```
.navbar {
background-color: purple;
border: transparent;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px grey;
margin: 0;

}

a{color:red;}
```

If you are using a framework and need it to change use !important.  !important changes a style that was already set.

```
.navbar {
background-color: purple;
border: transparent;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px grey;
margin: 0;

}

a{color:red!important;}
```

Comment: It didn't work, I'm using codepen, maybe that is the reason that it is not working?

Comment: ok give me a min ill check it out.  if you are trying to change the link colors this must be done in the a tag'

Comment: I updated my answer to place color on the a tags.  a tags have built in styling it has a default color and a underline or text decoration you need to change them specifically not by the parent.

Comment: When I put style="color: white;" inside the <a> tag it works, but is this the only way? It makes the code looks strange.

Comment: a tags have built in styling it has a default color and a underline or text decoration you need to change them specifically not by the parent

Comment: I think the correct way of doing this is not with important, but css specificity. And changing whatever we need from bootstrap sass/less variables :)

Comment: i agree this is an option but it also depends if he or she is going to use the default css framework in another page

Comment: Just one more question, about what @zalog said, there is another way of changing the color without the important? Because I'd to put !imporatant in every thing that I wanted to change in my navbar

Comment: @Igu, you can [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845660/2977191), I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add font color to your nav css `{color: #fff}` or if you just want to change the text color of your links then `.navbar a {color: #fff}` for example. You can do the same for all variations of links  `.navbar a, .navbar a:hover, .navbar a:visited {color: #fff}`

Comment: I've tried this before and it didn't work, such a basic problem and I can't find why this is happening

Comment: then your bootsrap is overriding changes to the css so 
.navbar { color: #fff !important}

Answer (score 0):

You can append color to the navbar class like so color: #whatevercoloryouchoose

it should look like this

```
.navbar {
 color: #whatevercoloryoulike;
 background-color: purple;
 border: transparent;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px grey;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm sure this wouldn't be specific enough to override colors set on children elements of the navbar.

Comment: note a # is only for hex colors black would be #000000 you dont need # sign unless you are using these types of hex colors. you could use green, blue, black and so on.  Add a real color for the example please.