# overriding API CSS REACT

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this CSS that got added in with a view component that stretching my images inside that component, which I do not want.

[image]

The CSS I'd like to get rid of is the crossed out stuff in dev tools. This is not in my CSS file this just came with the component. How do I get rid of them? The CSS I have currently is adequate for what I need and this added CSS is not what I want. Also am I phrasing the question correctly? Is it override API CSS? Or override bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Just add these css into any css file
. Carousel .slide img {
width: auto ! important
}

Let me know if you have any issue...

Comment: It's a good idea to try and avoid `!important` as it's very hard to overwrite, which introduces maintainability issues. OP can use more specific selectors to overwrite the initial CSS rules

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to override the default CSS classes would be adding **!important** to your CSS file only if it is a crucial state. But it is not much recommended. If you don't have any other option then use this or else do not.

I think the below link will also help you know the different ways of overriding the CSS file:
[What does !important in CSS mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean)