# How to change the color of an li item of the context menu, when hovered over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am developing an application using VueJS and Bootstrap. I have developed a context menu using the npm module called as vue-context [Vue Context Menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-context)

So when hovered over an item on the context menu, the option gets highlighted in blue color like this:

[image: Context menu]

The code looks like this:

```js
<vue-context ref="menu">
    <ul style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; ">
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fa fa-file' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Preview</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Share</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-copy" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Copy/Move</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='far fa-star' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Add to Starred</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-cloud-download-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Download</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Rename</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-tag' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Tags</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Delete</span></li>
        <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-chart-bar" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Access Stats</span></li>
    </ul>
</vue-context>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

I want to be able to change the color to a different color when hovered over an item. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: please add a working code snippet. thanks

Comment: It appears to be working just fine in [the demo](https://rawilk.github.io/vue-context/). You must have something else overwriting the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a css rule for the `.context-menu-item` class:

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    VueContext
  },
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick(text) {
      console.log(test)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.context-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-context@3.4.0/dist/vue-context.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open">
      Right click on me
    </p>
  </div>
  <vue-context ref="menu">
    <ul style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; ">
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fa fa-file' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Preview</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Share</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-copy" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Copy/Move</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='far fa-star' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Add to Starred</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-cloud-download-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Download</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Rename</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-tag' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Tags</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Delete</span></li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-chart-bar" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Access Stats</span></li>
    </ul>
  </vue-context>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine now. I realized that I hadn't included !important. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css) to get more information of `!important` in css.