# CSS trouble - changing colour of a link in cookie bar

Tags: css

I've got a CSS prob i'd love some help with.

My site (www.melodylakerart.com) has a 'Read More' link in its cookie notice bar (to the right of the privacy notice).

The 'read more' link is currently only visible on mouse over. Since the cookie bar is black I therefore assume the link text is black untill mouseover

I just want to make the text a colour other than black so you can see the link without having to mouseover. I've tried the below CSS with no luck. Can anyone help?

```
 .cn-more-info .cn-privacy-policy-link .cn-link .button {color: #feb8b4 !important;}
```

`.cn-privacy-policy-link {color: #feb8b4;}`

`.cn-more-info .cn-privacy-policy-link .cn-link .button {color: #feb8b4;}`

Comment: Maybe `#cn-more-info{ color: #feb8b4 !important }`

Comment: Thanks Alex - this fixed it! Genius

Answer (score 0):

Link color can be changed via `a:link` or under a specific class
`.cn-privacy-policy-link a:link`

for example:

```css
a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
}

a:active {
  color: black;
}

a:hover{
  color: #bada55;
}

.test a:link{
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Example</a>
<div class="test"><a href="www.yahoo.com">Yellow link</a></div>
```

You can also change the link color on hover by `a:hover` or the link color after being clicked by `a:visited` or while being clicked with `a:active`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have this:

```
input[type="submit"], button, .button {... color: #000000!important; ...}
```

And that is the classic reason why `!important` is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css).

If all other parts work as expected, you need to trigger one of the element's classes. For instance: `cn-privacy-policy-link {color: #feb8b4!important;}` will work.