# css does not apply style to templates in django

Tags: css, django

The theme applied by css does not work. In the past it used to apply but i do not what i did that its not executable anymore. `base.htmnl` is core template for other pages.

In `base.html` i have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'nana/css/main.css' %}"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class='navbar mynav-fixed-top navbar-expand-lg bg-dark' role='navigation' id='navbar'>
      <div class="container-fluid">

      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">

    {% block content %}

    <div class="main">

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

```
main.css

body{background-color: yellow}
```

`settings.py`   :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
```

The css does not work. I do not knwow why the application does not apply changes in css file. Would appreciate your though and help how to fix it.

Comment: try body{background-color: yellow !important} . [!important](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/) will force to use that css property value only. In your base.html keep your static import link for main.css below bootstrap import link. Also make sure you have called `python manage.py collectstatic` command after making any changes in static files.

Comment: Please grab the css URL from rendered page and open it manually in the browser - what's the error message/response status?

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Try using a classname or an `id`, rather than the tag name. Also try locating the link to the css file at the very bottom of your other `link` tags

Comment: Please add full css file URL (which gives 404) to your question and show your project folder structure. Also please clarify if you are running the project with DEBUG=true or false, show INSTALLED_APPS, mention Django version.

Comment: Debug is False. For full css file url you mean : http://www.nana.com/css/main.css ?

Comment: No, the full url from rendered page. In the browser make "View page source" and take the url from there.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is best to have the link to your own custom stylesheet (in your case that is `main.css`) after the other stylesheets in the `head`-section. The bootstrap stylesheets may overwrite your `main.css` thus making it useless.
You have the link to `main.css` before the links to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You better set STATIC_ROOT instead of STATICFILES_DIRS if this is the only folder with static files in your project:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

and change this `{% load staticfiles %}` to this `{% load static %}` in your templates - `load staticfiles` method is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#features-deprecated-in-2-1) since 2.1.

Also, as already suggested in comments, put your stylesheet after all the thirdparty stylesheets - thus it will have higher priority. Also note that your style may have lower priority if any of prior stylesheets defines the same property with `!important` [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245360/5921826).

Comment: Please answer my question asked in comments.

Comment: i have answered please see the comments

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the STATIC_ROOT, that's why your css is not showing up.

First Make sure in settings.py the debug setting is True

```
Debug=True
```

Put following code in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticroot')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

in your main urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # other urls
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and then call following command

```
>python manage.py collectstatic
```