# Add CSS to Embed Button with ID and Class from Bucket.io

Tags: css

I have this embed code:

```
<center><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-io-widget-assets/home/styleBucket.css"><button style="font-size: 24px;background-color:#7dba3f;color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid black;border-color:white;padding:10px 20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="lunchModal('https://go.bucketforms.com/sf/7ee7ca1c')" id="myBtnBucket" class="btn-outline-bucket gtm-cta">Claim Guide</button><div id="myModalButton" class="modalBucket"><div class="modal-content-bucket"> <span class="close-bucket">X</span></div></div> <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-io-widget-assets/home/scriptBucket.js" type="text/javascript"></script></center>
```

The button ID is "myBtnBucket" an the class is "btn-outline-bucket gtm-cta", but when attaching some CSS to that class, it's not working. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz9jcs8n/).

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use inline style, and the `<link>` tag should be placed in the 'head' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you wanted to set the background of the button to red,
with the following css it works. 
I removed the a, because there is no `a` element.

The `!important` tag basically overrules any style given directly in the `style=""` of the element, some better explenation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css#9245360).

```
.btn-outline-bucket.gtm-cta:hover{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```