# Change CSS on smartphone/tablet

Tags: css

I have a div with a float: right, it works very well on a computer screen, on the other hand on phone / tablet I would like this div to go to float: left.
How can I go about integrating this condition into my CSS?

Thank you for any help and explanation.

Comment: Try looking up `@media` queries :) they let you do that

Comment: If you just getting started with responsive and want to learn, I would suggest that you look into some tutorial on how to do [responsive design](https://www.creativebloq.com/rwd/responsive-web-design-tutorials-71410085). There is a mental model that is really good to have when doing so, that is [Mobile first](https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/mobile-first-design/). I see a few answers doing `max-width`, don't fall for that approach (please don't). If you want to get standard media queries then I suggest that you look at these from [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `media queries`

If the browser window is 600px or smaller, the background color will be lightblue:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "lightgreen".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can check this link also https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand !

Comment: I've understood your answers and I thank you for that. 

So I had : 

    .group-input {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      float: right;
      padding-left: 10px;
      text-align: right;
     }

I add below : 
@media (max-width: 572px) {
.group-input {
  float: left; !important
 }
}

But it's not taken ... How to force it ?

Comment: use `!important` in end of your styling to override all style to this. If your condition is correct then style will execute.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css

Answer (score 0):

You need Media Queries :)
Useful resources

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

Comment: Thank you very much !