# What does `!important` without a value mean in CSS?

Tags: css, webpack, next.js

**Situation:**

I am trying to use bootstrap 4 stylesheet with NextJS. The bootstrap 4 stylesheet (which is complied from SASS) has many codes like:

```
.checkbox.checkbox-accent > span {
  border-width: !important;
}
```

which breaks the production build of NextJS, i.e. when issue `yarn build` I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ next build
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /home/musa/codes/paisaha/finance-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:441:19
    at async /home/musa/codes/paisaha/finance-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:1441
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

However when I add a value before the `!important` in CSS the build problem is gone, e.g:

```
.checkbox.checkbox-accent > span {
  border-width: unset !important;
}
```

**Question:**

What does `!important` without a value mean and is it a valid CSS piece of code? Or is it a problem with SASS compilation? Or it is something with webpack compiler used by NextJS?

**Notes:**

- `yarn dev` works fine
- `"dependencies": { "next": "10.0.6", "react": "17.0.1", "react-dom": "17.0.1" }`
- NodeJS version: v12.18.2
- Platform: WSL2 on Windows 10

Comment: I think you’re missing variables. Check what the original SASS is. It’s probably something like `border-width: $border-width !important` but your value for the `$border-width` variable is an empty string (if it were completely undefined it wouldn’t compile)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does !important mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css)

Comment: @SuperStormer thanks for the input, but not, this is a totally different situation

Comment: @andrewtweber Thanks, this fixed my problem. Why wouldn't you post it as an answer?!

Comment: It felt like too much of a guess. Posted as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’re missing variables.

Check what the original SASS is. It’s probably something like:

```
border-width: $border-width !important;
```

But your value for the `$border-width` variable is an empty string (if it were completely undefined it wouldn’t compile)

Answer (score 3):

I tested !important in a sass file(in vs code) without any property value and it yelled at me:

> property value expectedscss(css-propertyvalueexpected)

So, it hasn't any special meaning. I think there may be a problem in your code before compilation that generates this line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and the general flow. However I am using a template which has a lot of complex logic (which I do not want to debug now) which suppresses the errors or warnings for SASS