# Extend HR width to all screen ignoring container's width

Tags: html, css

I have an `HR` element inside a **50%'s width** `div` container and I would like the `HR` to extend to all the width of the screen ignoring it's parent width.

I know I can solve this by applying the `HR` outside the container and use relative position to make it move where it has to be... but is there another solution?

I tried setting the width more than `100%`, lets say `300%` and let it overflow, but it will only enlarge to the right (and show an ugly scrollbar).

Browser treat `HR` as a block but I was unable to center it with `margin: 0 auto` (after resizing it as above).

Is there a way to accomplish this without relative positioning?

Comment: Try with `!important;`. See also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946645/how-to-ignore-parent-css-style).

Comment: A child element is not supossed to ignore of the container. !important would only be usefull if I had two styles applied to the same element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative margin for the `hr` like this:

```
hr {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnLrt/1/)

Note, these %s will only extend to the end of the viewport if its parent `div` is at the top level and/or no other parent has `width`, `padding`, or `margin` attached.
To handle that, maybe try a `width: 9999px; margin-left: -3333px;` and an `overflow: hidden` on the `body`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question after searching for a similar thing. Since (sadly) I didn't find a CSS-only solution for this problem, I ended up using jQuery to do the job.

```
function hrExpand() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   $('hr').width(windowWidth).css('margin-left', function(){
     return '-' + ($(this).offset().left) + 'px';
   });
}
```

Just make sure to run the function both onload and onresize.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEOoGb

*(You could replace $('hr') with e.g. $('.content > hr') to increase performance a bit and prevent it from replacing ALL the hr's on your page)*

Answer (score 0):

If you use the right values, using relative positioning works without a scrollbar:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

If a div is 50%, and you want the hr to be 100% of the root (twice as big as 50%), use 200%. For a 25% div, use a 400% hr, etc

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LwPfK/)

Answer (score 0):

If working with tailwind:

```
<hr class="my-2 -ml-10 -mr-10"/>
```

I have not tested bootstrap