# Ignore CSS rules if in specific element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have a class called `.root` which contains a lot of CSS rules which applies to almost all of my website.

I also have some "special" elements (included in the `.root` one), but I don't want to apply the `.root` rules to whatever is included in `.special` elements. I don't want to "override" all root rules, just not apply them.

Is it possible using only CSS?

Thank you!

```css
.root {
  color: blue;
  
  /* Lots of other styles */
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  This is blue
  
  <div class="special">
    <span>This is bold and blue, but I'd like this to be only bold</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's the best practice but ---- .root .special { css here overwrite !important }

Comment: You may be looking for `all: initial` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955184/7657915) so you don't need to make counter-rules for every single rule the parent has.

Answer (score 0):

you can use value `property:initial` to one property to the have the initial value of this property

or you can use `all: initial`to set all value of a selector to their inital value

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/initial

```css
.root {
  color: blue;
  
  /* Lots of other styles */
}

.special {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  This is blue
  
  <div class="special">
    <span>This is bold and blue, but I'd like this to be only bold</span>
  </div>
</div>
```